# ASP.NET MVC Routing: subfolder-like route

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing, maproute

This is my file structure in my ASP.NET MVC 4 project, regarding controllers:

```
 |--Models
 |--Controllers
       |
       |--api
       |   |
       |   |--UsersController.cs  (MyProject.Controllers.API.UsersController.cs)
       |   |--PlacesController.cs (MyProject.Controllers.API.PlacesController.cs)
       |
       |--UsersController.cs  (MyProject.Controllers.ViewsControllers.UsersController.cs)
       |--PlacesController.cs  (MyProject.Controllers.ViewsControllers.PlacesController.cs)
```

The controllers under namespace MyProject.Controllers.API all return JsonResult
The controllers under namespace MyProject.Controllers.ViewsControllers all return Views

My RouteConfig.cs is this:

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/",
            defaults: new { controller = "Places", action = "List" },
            namespaces: new[] { "MyProject.Controllers.ViewsControllers" }
        );
    }
```

When I go with the web browser to `http://localhost/Places/List`, it returns the view, as expected, because it uses the controller `MyProject.Controllers.PlacesControlller.cs`

How can I create a MapRoute for my json controllers so that when I go with the web browser to `http://localhost/api/Places/SomeAction`, it uses the class `MyProject.Controllers.API.PlacesController.cs` ?

Note: I don't want to use ASP.NET MVC's api feature

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "ViewRoute",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/",
            namespaces: new[] { "MyProject.Controllers.ViewsControllers" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "APIRoute",
            url: "api/{controller}/{action}/",
            namespaces: new[] { "MyProject.Controllers.API" }
        );
    }
```

Comment: check this http://bubblogging.wordpress.com/2012/06/09/mvc-routing-namespaces/

Comment: ok now I see whats happening: if I change "url: api/..." to "url: apix/..." it works. Apparently "api" is reserved.

Comment: At the end "api" was not reserved, but already being used as in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25277926/is-api-reserved-in-asp-net-mvc-routes - I don't know if closing this question will affect my reputation but I will like to leave that other question instead of this one.

Answer (score 1):

For calling normal controller action you have to register your routes like this which you have already done:

```
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "ViewRoute",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/",
        namespaces: new[] { "MyProject.Controllers.ViewsControllers" }
    );
```

For Calling api controller define following method in you routes class and register this method in your global.asax Application_Start() method :

```
    public static void RegisterAPI(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```