# Is "api/" reserved in ASP.NET MVC routes?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I don't want to use ASP.NET MVC WebApi, but I do want to use the URL /api/controller/action so that it is handled by my own controller

I'm doing this:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "APIRoute",
            url: "api/{controller}/{action}/",
            namespaces: new[] { "MyProject.Controllers.APIControllers" }
```

But it seems that is not possible to use `api/` in MapRoute(...)

If I navigate to `http://localhost/api/Blah/List` it doesn't work

If I change the route to this:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "APIRoute",
            url: "apix/{controller}/{action}/",
            namespaces: new[] { "MyProject.Controllers.APIControllers" }

        (Notice the 'x' in 'apix/')
```

And then I navigate to `http://localhost/apix/Blah/List` it works as expected

What can I do? is it possible to override `api/` ?

Comment: What is the solution now? What should be deleted or changed? There is absolutely no documentation on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you may have created a new project which includes Web API which is why you're having a hard time.

Search your project for `WebApiConfig` or `DefaultApi` - if you have any results then Web API has been added to your project and you'll want to amend the default `routeTemplate` which is by default `api/{controller}/{id}`.

Comment: You are right! I have WebApiConfig in App_Start and there is routeTemplate: "api/...", which is causing the problem. Thanks. I set "webapi/" for that route (which I don't use) and "api/" for my route

Comment: @sports Could you be more specific about that? Where is this "routeTemplate"m how to change it?